# Ubuntu Software Center Crashing

Tags: upgrade, software-center, 14.10

I recently installed an upgrade for Ubuntu, however due to a mis-click, I accidentally aborted the update installation in between.

Since then my software center has stopped working. It just keeps on crashing.

I tried several commands, tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software center as well.

However when I run `software-center` from the terminal, it gives this output:

```
nrbhyagrwl@nrbhyagrwl-Ubuntu:~$ software-center

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkImage:stock is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkImageMenuItem:use-stock is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkImageMenuItem:image is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkSettings:gtk-menu-images is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:top-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:bottom-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:left-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/SimpleGtkbuilderApp.py:32: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:right-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

2015-01-17 11:41:38,231 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-01-17 11:41:39,322 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-01-17 11:41:39,461 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-01-17 11:41:40,586 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2015-01-17 11:41:40,587 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:560: Warning: Source ID 74 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:560: Warning: Source ID 76 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py:95: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:xscale is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  Gtk.Alignment.__init__(self, xscale=1.0, yscale=1.0)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py:95: Warning: The property GtkAlignment:yscale is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  Gtk.Alignment.__init__(self, xscale=1.0, yscale=1.0)

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/description.py:418: Warning: The property GtkImageMenuItem:accel-group is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  Gtk.STOCK_COPY, None)

No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2200Mhz, 3918MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2200Mhz, 3918MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:001] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:012] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:012] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:012] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2200Mhz, 3918MB
[000:012] Computer model: Not available
[000:002] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:002] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:002] Cpu: 6.23.10, x2, 2200Mhz, 3918MB
[000:002] Computer model: Not available
[000:002] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:002] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:002] Using Gtk2 toolkit
**

Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.15.3+git20150113.f26986a5/./gtk/gtkstylecontext.c:2929:_gtk_style_context_validate: assertion failed: (!gtk_style_context_is_saved (context))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try running sudo dpkg --configure -a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finish doing the updates. Once that's done, uninstall and purge the Software Center by running:

```
apt-get purge software-center
```

And then restore it with:

```
apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: @EliahKagan: thanks for the edit!  Eagle-eyes to have noticed that point in the wrong place!  There should be a badge for this! ;-)

Comment: Brutal method =)